# Is production certificate and provisioning same for all dev machines (macmini)

Tags: ios

I have created a production certificate and provisioning profile via Enterprise account and it is working successfully from the machine i created a certificate but when from the other machine I am downloading and installing both certificate and provisioning, it is giving code signing error.

I tried then export p12 from my keychain and then imported to the other machine but still no success.

Any idea or please provide a link how single production certificate & provisioning can be used from different machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you export the private keys associated with the certificate.

Keychain Access->Keys->**Your Private Key**-> Right-click and "export"

The certificate associated with that key should be "under", as in nested-treeview, the private key you want to export.

Answer (score 0):

Export Private key is the right solution for multiple development machines for Certificates. Apple does not document this anywhere.
You also need a password associate with the private key export.